# Python Pandas: Querying fails with KeyError for one column out of many

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to query data frame

```
In [6]: books.dtypes
Out[6]:
count             float64
product             int64
channel             int64
book_start_year      int64
book_start_week      int64
book_end_year        int64
book_end_week        int64
period            float64
dtype: object

In [8]: print(books.columns.tolist())
['count', 'product', 'channel', 'book_start_year', 'book_start_week', 'book_end_year', 'book_end_week', 'period']
```

with:

```
books[books.channel == 1]
```

works ok, but this one:

```
books[books.product == 1]
```

fails with **KeyError** (please, see below). Data frame was read in from csv file previously written with Pandas just a minute ago under MacOS with command:

```
books = pd.read_csv('boxes2.csv', header=0)
```

Resetting or setting index to another column does not help either. Any ideas?

**UpdatE**

How then should I write query like this:

```
    data = books[(books.start_year >= start_year)
                 & (books.start_week >= start_week)
                 & (books.end_year <= end_year)
                 & (books.end_week <= end_week)
                 & (books.product == product)
                 ]
```

Or I can not?

Error:

```
    In [5]: books[books.product == 1]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-5-c6883f7202ed> in <module>()
    ----> 1 books[books.product == 1]

    /Users/user/usr/anaconda_2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _getitem_column(self, key)
       2002         # get column
       2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
    -> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
       2005
       2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

    /Users/user/usr/anaconda_2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item\
)
       1348         res = cache.get(item)
       1349         if res is None:
    -> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
       1351             res = self._book_item_values(item, values)
       1352             cache[item] = res

    /Users/user/usr/anaconda_2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in get(self, item, fastpath\
)
       3288
       3289             if not isnull(item):
    -> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
       3291             else:
       3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

    /Users/user/usr/anaconda_2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method,\
 tolerance)
       1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
       1946             except KeyError:
    -> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
       1948
       1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

    pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

    pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

    pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

    pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

    KeyError: False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product` is a method you need to use quotes to access your column because methods are looked up first before column names, accessing columns as an attribute is a convenience but it's error prone so you should use square brackets:

```
books[books['product'] == 1]
```

One should think of dataframes as a `dict` of `Series` so much like a normal dict you can pass a `Key` to return a `Value` which in this case will be the column or Series.

Note that ipython shows the following for `product`:

```
Signature: df.product(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Return the product of the values for the requested axis

Parameters
----------
axis : {index (0), columns (1)}
skipna : boolean, default True
    Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result
    will be NA
level : int or level name, default None
    If the axis is a MultiIndex (hierarchical), count along a
    particular level, collapsing into a Series
numeric_only : boolean, default None
    Include only float, int, boolean columns. If None, will attempt to use
    everything, then use only numeric data. Not implemented for Series.

Returns
-------
prod : Series or DataFrame (if level specified)
File:      c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.1\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
Type:      method
```

So this isn't documented but it's the same as [`prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html#pandas.DataFrame.prod)

This also strongly suggests you stop accessing columns as attributes as it leads to strange errors, get into the habit of using `[]` to access the columns to avoid this in the future

**EDIT**

to answer your updated question, use `[]` to access all columns:

```
data = books[(books['start_year'] >= start_year)
                 & (books['start_week'] >= start_week)
                 & (books['end_year'] <= end_year)
                 & (books['end_week'] <= end_week)
                 & (books['product'] == product)
                 ]
```

Although technically you only need to do this for product column, you should get into the habit of doing this for all columns

Comment: @piRSquared SO voting patterns are unpredictable much like Presidential elections and Brexit ;)